# is SIP:480 after 180 ringing same as SIP:480 after 183?

Tags: sip, voip, wireshark

1. when a calls with SIP:480 after SIP:180 is a user behavior, is it same with a calls with SIP:480 after SIP:183?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The difference between the 180 and 183 responses is the 183 response typically includes an SDP payload which makes an offer to provide an audio progress indication (fancy ringtone). As far as the meaning of the `480 Unavailable` response it's the same no matter which information responses preceded it.